# Lyx, harvard style reference help

Tags: cross-referencing, lyx

i need to produce the following reference style in Lyx ->  (AKAMAI, 2013). i'm Having lots of problems in finding a way to produce the above mentioned reference style. 
Any help how to achieve this ? I'm using Lyx 2.0.7 on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

Though it's a bit more complex to set up, I'd recommend using biblatex with LyX. You can then customise almost anything using latex macros in your document preamble. See http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex

Enable biblatex citation styles package.

Document settings ->Bibliography enable Natbib and author-year style

Add the bibliography the LyX way (Insert->List/TOC->Bibliography) and then put it in a Note box. (This lets you use the normal insert citation dialog.

Add the necessary lines to you document preamble, which includes the `\addbibresource` command. Note that “natbib=true” is essential to allow the use of LyX’s citation dialog.

Customise the author’s name in the preamble.

If you want to use biber, make sure to select that as the processor both in the preamble and in the Bibliography settings.

You insert the bibliography in the document by using the `\printbibliography` command in ERT.

A minimal example is below:

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex/biblatex-examples.bib}

%%%%%%%%
% Capitalise author's name 
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamelast}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
biblatex
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package default
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman default
\font_sans default
\font_typewriter default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command biber
\index_command default
\paperfontsize default
\spacing single
\use_hyperref false
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine natbib
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblio_style plainnat
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 3
\tocdepth 3
\paragraph_separation indent
\paragraph_indentation default
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Standard
Enable biblatex citation styles package.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Document settings ->Bibliography enable Natbib and author-year style
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Add the bibliography the LyX way (Insert->List/TOC->Bibliography) and then
 put it in a Note box.
 (This lets you use the normal insert citation dialog.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Add the necessary lines to you document preamble, which includes the `
\backslash
addbibresource` command.
 Note that 
\begin_inset Quotes eld
\end_inset

natbib=true
\begin_inset Quotes erd
\end_inset

 is essential to allow the use of LyX
\begin_inset Quotes ers
\end_inset

s citation dialog.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Customise the author
\begin_inset Quotes ers
\end_inset

s name in the preamble.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
If you want to use biber, make sure to select that as the processor both
 in the preamble and in the Bibliography settings.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
You insert the bibliography in the document by using the `
\backslash
printbibliography` command in ERT.
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand citet
key "doody"

\end_inset


\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand citep
key "doody"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Check out the LyX wiki 
\begin_inset Flex URL
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

http://wiki.lyx.org/BibTeX/Biblatex
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout


\backslash
printbibliography
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset Note Note
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset CommandInset bibtex
LatexCommand bibtex
bibfiles "/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/bibtex/bib/biblatex/biblatex/biblatex-examples"
options "apa"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: I think your answer would be more complete if you described how to use Biblatex to achieve the result that the OP is looking for.